# Sharepoint 2010: How to create an Item level permission allowing users to add and edit but not delete?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to create a custom group (ease of maintenance) for users that allow them to only add and edit items in LISTS. This group should not be able to edit any of the web parts on the web pages or delete an item in a list.

My Problem is:

When creating the custom Permission Levels the edit option also gives the option for web parts.

If you go down to list level and break the inheritance then you can give the “Contribute” option but this includes the delete option.

A possible solution would be to create an event receiver checking if the user is in this group and then not allowing them to delete an item but then the delete option is available in the ribbon.

Is there an easier way to allow a user group to only add and edit items without allowing them to delete items or edit web parts?

Any help or guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer Thanks to a comment from Ramesh on my [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/6d24fe66-937b-4ee0-a203-6e14f619c174) question

I needed to create custom permission levels in PowerShell. [Adding permission levels in SharePoint 2010 using PowerShell](http://www.powershell.nu/2010/12/19/adding-permission-levels-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/)